# How to perform Cause Validation with CheckBox?

Tags: asp.net

By default cause Validation is false in case of checkBox but I want to perform some operation (any operation) when cause validation is true. how to do this?

Comment: please  specify what you want to do with checkBox

Comment: what is there to validate? the only values are true and false

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `CausesValidation` property to true, and don't forget to make the postback happen automatically too, to actually have a postback on the server:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="MyCheckBox" runat="server" 
Text="What about this?" 
AutoPostBack="True" 
CausesValidation="True"
/>
```

Clicking on the TextBox then will invoke all validators on the page. Is that what you wanted?